# how to find out which label tapped on without initializing gestureRecognizer.view to label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have labels in my ios app that are enabled to respond to tap gestures. In order to change the properties of the label that was tapped, I find out which label was tapped by doing this

```
CustomLabel * label = gestureRecognizer.view;
```

and then changing the properties I wish to accordingly. However, the line of code above issues a warning

`incompatible pointer type initializing CustomLabel with an expression of type UIView`

What would be a proper way of doing this without getting a warning?

```
-(void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        return;

    CustomLabel * label = gestureRecognizer.view;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting will do the trick

```
CustomLabel * label = (CustomLabel*)gestureRecognizer.view;
```